# How to correct this code to avoid old-style-cast warnings with C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm new to c++ and I'm trying to avoid old-style-cast warning in a piece of code during compilation. The code is a part of some old opensource code. Here is the code itself:

```
#define ROUND_TO_BYTE(X)      ((BYTE)((X)+0.499))
#define ROUNDS(X)             ((short)((X)+0.499))
#define TRUNC(X)              ((short) (X))

#define CONVERT_DOUBLE_TO_FLOAT(val) \
  ( (val) >= SMALLFLOAT \
    ? ( (val) < LARGEFLOAT \
        ? (float)(val) \
        : (float)LARGEFLOAT \
      ) \
    : ( (val) <= -SMALLFLOAT  \
        ? ( (val) > -LARGEFLOAT \
            ? (float)(val) \
            : (float)-LARGEFLOAT \
          ) \
        : (float)0.0 \
      ) \
  )
```

I have tried as follow and the code does compile without any warning:

```
#define ROUND_TO_BYTE(X)      (static_cast<BYTE>((X)+0.499))
#define ROUNDS(X)             (static_cast<short>((X)+0.499))
#define TRUNC(X)              (static_cast<short>(X))


#define CONVERT_DOUBLE_TO_FLOAT(val) \
  ( (val) >= SMALLFLOAT \
    ? ( (val) < LARGEFLOAT \
        ? static_cast<float>(val) \
        : static_cast<float>(LARGEFLOAT) \
      ) \
    : ( (val) <= -SMALLFLOAT  \
        ? ( (val) > -LARGEFLOAT \
            ? static_cast<float>(val) \
            : static_cast<float>(-LARGEFLOAT) \
          ) \
        : static_cast<float>(0.0) \
      ) \
  )
```

However I'm not sure if I get the following lines right:

```
#define TRUNC(X)              ((short) (X))
```

to

```
#define TRUNC(X)              (static_cast<short>(X))
```

and

```
        ? (float)(val) \
```

to

```
        ? static_cast<float>(val) \
```

I don't understand why using (float)(val) instead of (float)val and whether I need to change the code to:

```
#define TRUNC(X)              (static_cast<short>((X)))
? static_cast<float>((val)) \
```

Comment: **TL;DR** of the dupe - your change is fine as is, even though parentheses need to be added in general.

Comment: Just a minor quibble: presumably, the code is correct as written, and the goal is not to "**correct** this code to avoid ... warnings" but to "**change** this code to avoid ... warnings". This is a **style** issue, not a correctness issue.

Comment: @PeteBecker thank you, yes the code is correct! I just wanted to suppress the warnings by changing the code.

Comment: @StoryTeller thanks for the help.